# How to remove Scrollbar but don't remove scroll-thumb and how to indent this scroll-thumb?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to remove Scrollbar and scrollbar-track but don't remove scrollbar-thumb and this scrollbar-thumb indent left on 5 px;

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
    background-color: #ff8000;
}
```

Comment: For that you have to make your own scrollbar. The default scrollbar cant be modified using CSS

Comment: @JonesJoseph how to do it? draw? Have a link on the tutorials?

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ this one provides custom scrollbars and good thing is you can modify the css to your need.

Comment: @JonesJoseph thank you!